# intellij undo formatting CTRL+ALT+L

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting, undo

intellij: how to undo formatting CTRL+ALT+L? 
Now the svn diff is a mess.

CTRL+Z did not work.

svn revert: does not work since there are many changes in addition to formatting.

How to disable auto-formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+z works for me when I do a ctrl+alt+l.  You could also hit

```
Edit->Undo Reformat Code
```

If its on a Mac its cmd+z but I assume everyone knew that.

I am not 100% sure about svn, but in intellij you can view "Local History" of a file and revert to the "preformatted version"

[image: Screenshot of Local History]

[image]

Comment: could not find Edit->Undo Reformat Code. My version is 2109.2 on windows. There were changes after formatting.

Comment: The local history is good. But I tried to manually fixed the blank line diff(whitespace tabs removed) , so there were many changes after code formatting. It is difficult to find the local change before formatting. How to diff between neighbor revisions, but current?

Comment: If you click on the two versions you want to to compare on the left it will show the diff between neighboring versions. I will add a screenshot to the answer to show you.

Comment: You have to hold down the shift key and select them both.  I am on Linux but I assume it is the same on Windows.

Comment: Thanks. It did not show diff between selected two revisions, one position off.